# Phrase meaning using voyage

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I just want to know from a native speaker if the following two phrases convey the following meaning. I am on a journey of continuous learning and evolving. I am strictly interested in the below phrases and just want to know if they make sense

> On a voyage of endless learning path

OR

> On an endless voyage to learning path

Comment: I'm a native speaker. The first is bad English. The second is too, unless "Learning Path" is a destination you'll never reach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. On a voyage of endless learning path
> 2. On an endless voyage to learning path

Neither option is grammatically correct. The main problem is the redundancy of "voyage" and "path:" you can say "I am on an endless path of learning" **or** "I am on a voyage of endless learning" but you cannot combine the two.

If you simply remove the trailing "path" then the first option becomes acceptable and clear: "On a voyage of endless learning." This means exactly what you want it to mean.

Even if you remove "path," the second option is not idiomatic. You are trying to say that you are *continually learning*, but if you say you are on "a voyage **to** learning" that implies that you are trying to *start* learning once you reach the end of that (endless) voyage. You might make the destination "knowledge" or "enlightenment" or some other goal you can strive towards without truly reaching.

Answer (score 2):

(Native AmE speaker) If you change the second option to "on an endless journey of learning" it will sound better. That said, "endless" here suggests a tinge of frustration to me rather than joy. Is that the nuance you wanted? A more positive way to state this might be "a voyage of discovery" or a "nonstop journey of discovery."